# Android Compose lazycolumn does not update when livedata is changed

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

I have a list of items where each has a checkbox. The state of the checkbox needs to be stored in the `viewmodel` and preferable the list in the `viewmodel` should be the only source of truth.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    val list by viewModel.items.observeAsState()

    LazyColumn {
        list?.let { items ->
            items(items) { item -> 
                ListItem(
                    text = {
                        Text(item.name)
                    },
                    secondaryText = {
                        Text(item.phoneNumber)
                    },
                    icon = {
                        Checkbox(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                            checked = item.selected,
                            onCheckedChange = {
                                //TODO

                            }
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to update the `item.selected` by updating the list (`MutableLiveData<List<Object>>` in `viewmodel`) in the `onCheckedChange` callback, but the UI does not update. If i scroll down and then up the UI updates and the checkbox appears to be checked. Why does it not update?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MutableLiveData` knows nothing about the object it holds. It cannot send you new value when some inner object property is updated.

To solve this with live data, you need to set new value to you items, setting the same value will be enough:

```kotlin
fun setSelected(index: Int, selected: Boolean) {
    items.value!![index].selected = selected
    items.value = items.value
}
```

But if you're not bind to `LiveData` by other dependencies, I suggest you not using it. Using `mutableStateListOf` with immutable `data class` is much cleaner:

```kotlin
data class Object(val selected: Boolean)

class VM: ViewModel() {
    val items = mutableStateListOf<Object>()

    fun setSelected(index: Int, selected: Boolean) {
        items[index] = items[index].copy(selected = selected)
    }
}
```

In both cases, you need the object index, you can get it with `itemsIndexed`:

```kotlin
val list = viewModel.items
LazyColumn {
    itemsIndexed(list) { index, item -> 
        // ...
        onCheckedChange = {
            viewModel.setSelected(index, it)
        }
    // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***In my Case***

I were using a mutable list like

```
MutableLiveData<MutableList<Car>>()
```

I changed it to a list like this and it worked.  :(

```
MutableLiveData<List<Car>>()
```