# LiveData value not updating UI in Jetpack Compose until I navigate out

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am calling an *increaseCount(id: String)* method from a composable to increase the value of a parameter in a LiveData List of objects. The value gets updated quite alright but the UI only shows the update once I navigate out. PS: I am using a BottomNavigation view for navigating.

The Composable screen in question looks something like this

```
@Composabale
fun MyScreen(navController: NavHostController, viewModel: MyViewModel){
val itemList = viewModel.itemList.observeAsState().value
 LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        items(itemList) { item: Item? ->

            ItemView(item, viewModel)

        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ItemView(item: Item?, viewModel: MyViewModel) {
Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp, 0.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
        ) {
            //Counter section
            IconButton(onClick = { viewModel.decreaseItemCount(cartItem.itemId) }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.RemoveCircleOutline,
                    contentDescription = "Reduce order button",
                    tint = Color.Gray
                )
            }
            Text(text = "${item.itemQuantity}")
            IconButton(onClick = { viewModel.increaseItemCount(item.itemId) }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.AddCircleOutline,
                    contentDescription = "Increase order button",
                    tint = Color(R.color.yellow_700)
                )
            }
        }
```

The ViewModel side of things looks something like this:

```
private val _itemList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Item>>()
val itemList: LiveData<List<Item>>
  get() = _itemList

 fun increaseItemCount(id: String) {
    val theList = _itemList.value
    theList?.find { item ->
        item.itemId == id
    }?.let { item ->
        item.itemQuantity += 1
        _itemList.value = theList!!
    }
}
```

The *decreaseItemCount* function is similar to the *increaseItemCount* with the only difference being the count is decreasing.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71596921/3585796) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074376/3585796)

Comment: @PylypDukhov I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have modified the code to: `fun increaseItemCount(id: String) {
        val theList = _itemsList.value
        _itemsList.value?.find { item ->
            item.itemId == id
        }?.let { item ->
            item.itemQuantity += 1
            val index = _itemsList.value!!.indexOf(item)
            setSelected(index, item.itemQuantity)}}` and  `private fun setSelected(index: Int, itemQuantity: Int) {
        _itemsList.value!![index].itemQuantity = itemQuantity
        _itemsList.value = _itemsList.value
    }`

Comment: @PylypDukhov also tried the other solution, setting up another method to update the view using the object itself as a parameter such as:  `fun updateOne(item: Item) {
        val index = _convertedItemListLiveData.value?.indexOf(item)
        if (index != null) {
            _convertedItemListLiveData.value?.get(index)?.let {
                _convertedItemListLiveData.value?.set(index, it
                    .copy(itemUid = item.itemUid, itemQuantity = item.itemQuantity + 1)
                )
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: `_itemsList.value = _itemsList.value` cannot trigger recomposition, as this is the same object. my answers contains all needed information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you update an object property, `LiveData` cannot know that this object has changed. And a list still contains the same list of objects.

The solution is to actually create a new object with updated properties. data class is very comfy for this: declare your properties as `val` and update them using `copy`.

Check out [Why is immutability important in functional programming?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-important-in-functional-programming).

Live data version:

```
data class Item(val itemId: String, val itemQuantity: Int)

private val _itemList = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()
val itemList: LiveData<List<Item>>
    get() = _itemList

fun increaseItemCount(id: String) {
    val theList = _itemList.value?.toMutableList() ?: return
    val index = theList.indexOfFirst { it.itemId == id }
    if (index == -1) return
    theList[index] = theList[index].let {
        it.copy(itemQuantity = it.itemQuantity + 1)
    }
    _itemList.value = theList
}
```

`mutableStateListOf` version is a little bit shorted and cleaner:

```
data class Item(val itemId: String, val itemQuantity: Int)

private val _itemList = mutableStateListOf<Item>()
val itemList: List<Item> = _itemList

fun increaseItemCount(id: String) {
    val index = _itemList.indexOfFirst { it.itemId == id }
    if (index == -1) return
    _itemList[index] = _itemList[index].let {
        it.copy(itemQuantity = it.itemQuantity + 1)
    }
}
```